# Purpose of atomic structures

Tags: c, struct, atomic, c11

According to C11 § 6.5.2.3

```
Accessing a member of an atomic structure or union object results
in undefined behavior.
```

This makes sense since you cannot access a whole structure in general. Still why is `_Atomic` then also a type qualifier and not only a type specifier?

In other words what is the purpose of a structure which is qualified as `_Atomic`? I'm not allowed to either read or write to any element of it.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

struct {
    int x;
} _Atomic foo;

int main(void) {
    foo.x = 42;     // write error
    return foo.x;   // read error
}
```

Both accesses of `foo.x` result in a warning/error in GCC/Clang---which is perfectly fine w.r.t. the C11 standard. Why would I want to qualifier then a structure as `_Atomic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access individual members, but always the structure as a whole. Accessing parts of something that is meant to be an atomic unit, makes not much sense, I think.

A typical use case for an atomic structure is the combination of two pointers, e.g. the head and tail of a list. To manipulate such a `struct` you would have to copy the current value from the atomic to a temporary, modify that, and then copy back. By that you'd always have a guarantee that the stored value is consistent at any time.

Per default all such operations on a whole atomic `struct` have sequential consistency.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have expected such a behavior. If I can access the whole structure atomically, then I would have expected that I can also access a single element atomically. For me it seems like an overhead if I want to modify a single element, then I have to copy the whole structure two times. But I can imagine that such a behavior is far easier to specify and guarantee the same behavior on many architectures. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations might be able to guarantee atomic behavior for structures meeting certain criteria.  I don't know whether any implementations that did so actually existed before the publication of the C11 Standard, but it would certainly seems plausible.  If an implementation usefully supported such structures, it would have been rather annoying for the Standard to demand that they be treated as a constraint violation.

It would have been helpful if the Standard mandated, or at least suggested, that implementations treat as constraint violations any attempts to define atomic structures *for which they cannot offer proper semantics*, but for whatever reason the authors of the Standard seem extremely loath to recognize a category of programs that would be rejected by some implementations but have defined behavior on implementations that don't reject it.  A good standard should seek to maximize the number of useful programs that would fall into that category, but the Standard instead tends to regard constructs which some implementations will support and others won't as Undefined Behavior, letting implementations support them or not at their leisure, but not offering any safe way to determine whether they are supported.

Comment: The standard guarantees that *all* objects that are atomic qualified are consistent.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Guarantees of consistency are meaningless if the program invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: yes, so what? Your premise for a rant on the C committee is that there could be *"atomic structures for which an implementation cannot offer proper semantics"* . This premise is simply false. All `struct` types can be qualified atomic and the standard offers proper semantics for all of them. So no implementation of the C standard can ever be in such a situation.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Perhaps I should have said "offer proper semantics *for member access*" [which I would consider part of the semantics of a structure]?

Comment: perhaps, but I even understand less what that means. One of the properties of atomics is to be indivisible, asking in general for atomic `struct` to access individual members is going against that. Nobody should expect such an operation to be "easy" on any platform. Generally for `struct` this will be a sequence of load, modify the copy, and compare-exchange in a loop.

Comment: @JensGustedt: What is important with atomics is that *operations* on them are indivisible.  If one has a structure with an "enable" field along with some data, one may need to atomically set the "enable" field and load the data, but at other times one may want to be able to clear the enable field without having to do anything with the other data.  If "enable" will usually be false, code might benefit from reading the enable field and then, only if it's true, reading the entire structure (recognizing that if "enable" becomes false between the two reads, the effort of reading would be wasted).